# ModelSim-Altera show error "enum literal name already exists" while Quartus not

Tags: struct, enums, system-verilog, modelsim, quartus

Quartus compile this code without any errors.

**Code.sv**

```
module test013_LITERAL (
    input  A,
    input  B,
    output C
);
    struct{enum{IDLE,
                SOME_STAGE_1} FSM;
             logic some_register;
            } first_machine;
    struct{enum{IDLE,
                SOME_STAGE_2} FSM;
             logic some_register;
            } second_machine;            
    assign C = A ^ B;    
endmodule
```

**testbench.vt**

```
  module testbench();
reg test_A;
reg test_B;
wire test_C;

test013_LITERAL DUT (.A(test_A),
                     .B(test_B),
                     .C(test_C));
initial begin    
    #100
        test_A = 0;
        test_B = 0;
    #100
        test_A = 1;
        test_B = 0;    
    #100
        test_A = 0;
        test_B = 1;        
    #100
        test_A = 1;
        test_B = 1; 
end   
endmodule
```

But ModelSim-Altera show error: *"Enum literal name 'IDLE' already exists."*

Can I write on SystemVerilog two structs in one module and then make enum in each struct with same literal ("IDLE" for example)? Is another struct means another scope?

If not can anyone describe what structs are used for?

If yes can anyone describe to me how to win ModelSim-Altera?

**P.S.**

Of course if there is two enums in one module and if these enums has identical members we will have an error. But I say about enums witch placed into structs.

Example:

```
module test013_LITERAL (
    output [3:0]first_literal,
    output [3:0]second_literal
);

struct{enum{SOME_LITERAL_0_FIRST,
            SOME_LITERAL_1_FIRST,
            IDLE,
            SOME_LITERAL_3_FIRST,
            SOME_LITERAL_4_FIRST} enum_reg;
        } first_struct;

struct{enum{SOME_LITERAL_0_SECOND,
            SOME_LITERAL_1_SECOND,
            SOME_LITERAL_2_SECOND,
            IDLE,
            SOME_LITERAL_4_SECOND} enum_reg;
        } second_struct;

assign first_literal        = first_struct.IDLE;
assign second_literal   = second_struct.IDLE;

endmodule
```

Result of compilling on Quartus Prime 17.1.0 (MAX-10 10M02SCE144C8G):

*Info (293000): Quartus Prime Full Compilation was successful. 0 errors, 32 warnings*

Result on eight LED string: 0010 0011

**P.P.S.**

I don't understand if struct create new scope of not.

This code compile by Quartus as well as ModelSim-Altera without any errors.

```
module test013_LITERAL (
    input A,
    input B,
    output C
);
    logic some_register;
    struct{logic some_register;} first_struct;
    struct{logic some_register;} second_struct;         
    assign C = A ^ B;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE 1800-2012, section 6.19 says:

> ```
> // Correct declaration - bronze and gold are unsized
> enum bit [3:0] {bronze='h3, silver, gold='h5} medal2;
> // Correct declaration - bronze and gold sizes are redundant
> enum bit [3:0] {bronze=4'h3, silver, gold=4'h5} medal3;
> ```
>
> Type checking of enumerated types used in assignments, as
>   arguments, and with operators is covered in
>   6.19.3. As in C, there is no overloading of literals; therefore, medal2 and medal3 cannot be defined in the same scope because they
>   contain the same names

So, I would say that it is correct to report an error with your code because the `IDLE` literal appears twice.

I have tried your code on three simulators. One accepts it, the other two reject it. So, in total, three simulators reject your code, one accepts it (as does Quartus). I guess the fact that your enum is declared within a struct complicates the EDA vendors' interpretation of the standard.

The fix is to change the name of one or both (eg `IDLE1` and `IDLE2`).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you call the simulator witch accept my code?

Comment: As per section 23.9 Scope rules of IEEE 1800-2017, structs don't create scopes (but classes do), so `IDLE` is defined twice in the same scope.

Comment: Add P.P.S. with code example. 

I think if struct don't create scope at all they will be useless. For register scope created but not for enum elements.